# If $a_n$ is a positive sequence and $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}a_n=0$ then there exists $N>0$ such that $(a_{N+n})$ is decreasing

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

> If $a_n$ is a positive sequence and $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}a_n=0$ then there exists $N>0$ such that $(a_{N+n})$ is decreasing

---

The first way is by contradiction with an example:

let $
a_n=
\begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{n}&\text{if}\, n _{even}\\
 \frac {1}{2n}&\text{if}\, n_{odd}\\
\end{cases}
$

if $n$ is even then $\frac{1}{n} > 0$ and if $n$ is odd then $\frac {1}{2n}< \frac {1}{n}$ which is also greater than zero so according to squeeze theorem $0 < a_n < \frac {1}{n}$ so $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}a_n=0$ but for odd $n$ we have $n+1$ is even so $a_{n+1} = \frac {1}{n+1} > \frac {1}{2n} = a_n$ so there does not exist a natural $N$ such that the sequence $a_{N+n}$ decreases

I am trying to think of more ways to solve the question.

I do not know if I can do such thing but if we assume that $a_{N+n}$ is actually decreasing then $a_{N+n+1}-a_{N+n} \leq 0 < a_n$ which is a contradiction because $a_n >0$ so we get that it is increasing.

I also tried to assume that it is increasing $a_{N+n+1}-a_{N+n}>0$ and also because it is increasing we get $a_{N+n+1}-a_{N+n}>a_n$
I tried by induction to prove  $a_{N+n+1}-a_{N+n}>0$

so we check for $N=1$ : $a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}>0$

and assume for $N=k$ : $a_{k+n+1}-a_{k+n}>0$

and prove for $N=k+1$ : $a_{k+n+2}-a_{k+n+1}>0$

according to given information $a_n>0$,  the induction assumption and the assumption that the sequence is increasing we have  $a_{k+n+1}-a_{k+n}>a_n>0$

so  $a_{k+n+2}-a_{k+n+1}>a_{k+n+2}-a_{k+n}-a_n>0$ $\implies$ $a_{k+n+2}-a_{k+n+1}>a_{k+n+2}-a_{k+n}>a_n$ and as mentioned $a_n >0$ so our assumption is true and the sequence is increasing not decreasing

the other solutions felt a bit weird and incorrect , I am trying to learn as many ways as possible to solve questions .

Thanks for any help and tips!

Comment: Yours is the best, more mathematcially satisfying way to show what you want, which to contradict a general statement: show via an example that the statement is false.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you , are the 3 solutions I tried here right? or only the first solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The counterexample you gave is correct. This is sufficient to solve the problem given. As for what follows..

1. If we assume $(a_{N+n})$ is decreasing for some $N$, that means $a_{N+n+1} \leqslant a_{N+n}$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$. If this yields a contradiction, it does Not imply $(a_{N+n})$ is increasing.
2. If we assume $a_{N+n+1}-a_{N+n}>0$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$ it is not necessary to prove the same statement.